# For Loop to Store Rows with Accessory Icon to Array

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, for-loop

Need help with a for loop that I haven't quite gotten right. Been fussing with it too long and  figured I should just turn to the experts.

I need this to iterate through every index path and check on the accessory icon. If it's a check mark, add it to the array, then finally log the array.

This is all tied to a button action. Here's the code:

```
//Handles tableView row selection and addition and removal of the checkmark
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [theTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[theTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        //Reflect selection in data model
    } else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
         //Reflect deselection in data model
    }
}

    //Sends checkmarked items to console log
    - (IBAction)sendResults:(id)sender {
        NSMutableArray *aList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //This is the part that isn't quite right
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in _tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows) {
    NSString *r = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)indexPath.row];
    [aList addObject:r];
 }

        NSLog(@"Selected Items: %@", _aList);
}
```

I think the problem is none of my table view cells are selected. In my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, I check the accessory icon to a check mark, but then it seems to deselect the row. So there are no objects in `_tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows` when I log it (I get "Selected Items: (null)" in the log.

The problem makes sense, but I can't seem to iron out the solution. Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: you deselect the row before checking the accessory type

Answer (score 0):

In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you are deselecting the row. Therefore when your loop executes on the selected rows (_tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows) there are no entries. Displaying a check mark next to the row is different from having the UITableView actually recognize it as being selected.

To fix this either remove `[theTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[theTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];` or change your loop to test for `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`